# Check jdk availability

Tags: java

How can I manually check if jdk is installed on my machine, and if yes, what version?

If I had jdk in Windows 7, and now I installed Windows 8 separately on the same machine, do I need to reinstall the jdk? Or can I reuse it?

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` <- check that path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install java on windows it can go by default in one of the following locations:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
C:\Program Files\Java
```

If you look in both of these locations, you will see exactly which JDKs and JREs are installed.

If you installed it somewhere else and don't remember, you can still search for java.exe

If by "Can i use it", you mean for use with an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, the answer is yes. They can use the JDK files no matter where they are, and whether it has been installed on the OS or not.

`java -version` will only tell you about a java version that would be on the path, which is not always the case.

Comment: Java can actually be installed *anywhere*. It gives you the option to choose a non-default location when you install it. Regardless, +1, as OP would be the one to know if they installed Java in some obscure path.

Comment: @Vulcan thanks for this remark. I updated the post to address the issue more thoroughly

Answer (score 1):

If you have two Windows Version and the java installed in a place where both can share it, you can reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

In cmd window type

> java

If you see java usage information then you have java installed.

> java -version

which display current version of your java.

You may reuse it windows 7 java in windows 8.

Comment: We need to set environment variable for JAVA_HOME before CMD recognizes java.